# storing and calling of function's handlers for pandas' windows object

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

My question regards to [pandas' rolling window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) object and methods can be applied on it.

There are some methods we can use on a rolling window, such as `sum()`, `mean()` and etc. They can be found in [documentation section on Window object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/window.html).

I want to store a function handler and call upon it later on.
My goal is to receive a string from user, and then call to a function properly.

For example, if user input is `"Mean"` then I want to calculate the mean of a a rolling window:

`df_win = df.rolling('1d').mean()`

I want to support some cases, so I though to use a dictionary:

```py
dict_action = {"Mean":???, "Sum":???, "Std":???}
df_win = df.rolling('1d').??? # and somehow call to function stored in dict_action[usr_input]
```

As you can probably guess, I need help with fill `???` inside dictionary and how I call those function handlers.

So far I tried to put directly the function inside dictionary, for example `dict_action = {"Mean":pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean, ...}`

But when I tried to call to the function it didn't work, as it suppose to be for a specific window object.

I managed to do it "manually" using some if/else, but I guess there is a smarter way.

I know that one of the window acceptable functions is `apply` which allows me to pass every function I want. From what I see around here, pandas' apply function are inefficient and some people reluctant from using it. It is a possible solution, but I wonder if there is a better way by using directly window's methods rather then apply and then another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have this dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'values': np.random.randn(6)},
    index = pd.date_range('28-06-2020', periods=6, freq='8H')
)

                    values
2020-06-28 00:00:00 -1.846436
2020-06-28 08:00:00 -0.327604
2020-06-28 16:00:00 1.052729
2020-06-29 00:00:00 -1.087175
2020-06-29 08:00:00 0.268455
2020-06-29 16:00:00 1.223025
```

You can use [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) function to aggregate data with any function. For your actions you can take `np.mean`, `np.sum` and `np.std` functions from `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

dict_action = {"Mean": np.mean, "Sum": np.sum, "Std": np.std}
df_win = df.rolling('1d').agg(dict_action["Mean"])
```

Result:

```py
2020-06-28 00:00:00   -1.846436
2020-06-28 08:00:00   -1.087020
2020-06-28 16:00:00   -0.373770
2020-06-29 00:00:00   -0.120683
2020-06-29 08:00:00    0.078003
2020-06-29 16:00:00    0.134768
Freq: 8H, Name: values, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you, I was unfamiliar with that function. Seems appropriate for what I need

Answer (score 2):

A function that can work in your case is `.agg`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 3)))
df.rolling(3).agg(['mean', 'sum', 'std'])
```

As the user passes a string, if you lowercase it afterwards, it can be used in the `.agg` function.

```py
user_input='Mean'.lower()
df.rolling(3).agg([user_input])
```

Comment: Thank you, I was unfamiliar with that function. Seems appropriate for what I need